# Getting Error: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH on a Mac in Jupyter NoteBook

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

I know my query is very similar to other questions asked before, but I am working on a Jupyter NoteBook on a MacBook Air.
My file chrome driver.exe is stored on desktop and download
Can someone help me determine what is wrong with the code or path to file ?

My code lines are as follows and as show in the image:

from selenium import webdriver

PATH="users/aditisingh/desktop/chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUHqA.png)

Comment: Hi ! Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `chromedriver.exe` in the same directory as your Python script and run:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: can you send a screenshot of your project folder?

Comment: Check if you have installed the correct version that supports the chrome version.

Comment: It's the correct version. I deleted and re-downloaded as well.